# Basic Shading in C++ to a BMP image. Facing ratio calculation

Tags: c++, shading

I am studying Shading and how light interacts with objects. I found a great website and wanted to implement knowledge from https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/introduction-to-shading/shading-normals in my own way.

I wrote a code. It is supposed to calculate a facing ratio (*cosine of the angle between a normal vector and a light Ray* ) and generate a ".BMP" image with that. I took a surface as an object (well, on the image it will be a circle). The idea was to calculate the effect of this ratio on the color of the surface, i.e how light and object interact.

**The code is as follows**

```
    
template <typename T> 

class Vec3
{
private: 
    T x, y, z;
public:
    Vec3(): x{0},y{0},z{0} {}
    Vec3(T xx): x{xx}, y{xx},z{xx} {}
    Vec3(T xx, T yy, T zz): x{xx}, y{yy}, z{zz} {}

   friend Vec3<T> operator+(const Vec3<T>& vec1, const Vec3<T>& vec2) { return Vec3<T>(vec1.x + vec2.x, vec1.y + vec2.y, vec1.z + vec2.z); }
   friend Vec3<T> operator-(const Vec3<T>& vec1, const Vec3<T>& vec2) { return Vec3<T>(vec1.x - vec2.x, vec1.y - vec2.y, vec1.z - vec2.z); }
   friend Vec3<T> operator*(const Vec3<T>& vec1, const Vec3<T>& vec2) { return Vec3<T>(vec1.x * vec2.x, vec1.y * vec2.y, vec1.z * vec2.z); }
   friend Vec3<T> operator*(const Vec3<T>& vec1, const T& k) { return Vec3<T>(vec1.x * k, vec1.y * k, vec1.z * k); }
   friend Vec3<T> operator/(const Vec3<T>& vec1, const T& k) { return Vec3<T>(vec1.x / k, vec1.y / k, vec1.z / k); }
    Vec3<T> operator - () const { return Vec3<T>(-x, -y, -z); }

    T dot (const Vec3<T>& v) const { return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z; }
    T lengthWithoutRoot() const { return x * x + y * y + z * z; }
    T length() const { return sqrt(lengthWithoutRoot()); }

    Vec3& normalize()
    {
        T nor2 = lengthWithoutRoot();
        if (nor2 > 0) {
            T divider = 1 / sqrt(nor2);
            x *= divider, y *= divider, z *= divider;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3<T> reflection(const Vec3<T>& prim,const Vec3<T>& normal) // TO BE CHECKED 
    {
        Vec3<T> reflection = prim - 2 * (prim.dot(normal)) * normal;
        return reflection;

    }



    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Vec3<T>& vec)
    {
        out << '(' << vec.x << ',' << vec.y << ',' << vec.z << ')';
        return out;
    }

    const T& getX() { return x; }
    const T& getY() { return y; }
    const T& getZ() { return z; }





};

typedef Vec3<float> Vec3f;

class Sphere
{
private:
    Vec3f center;
    float radius;
public:
    Sphere(const Vec3f& c, const float& r): center{c}, radius{r} {}
    

    bool intersect(const Vec3f& primRay) 
       

    {
        Vec3f vecRadius = center - primRay;
        float distLength = vecRadius.length();
        
        if (distLength > radius)
            return false;

        
        return true;
    }

    bool intersectSurface(const Vec3f& primRay)
        
    {
        Vec3f vecRadius = center - primRay;
        float distLength = vecRadius.length();

        if (distLength == radius)
            return true;


        return false;
    }

        float alphaPositive(const Vec3f& p, const Vec3f& source)
    {
        
        Vec3f primRay = (source-p).normalize();
        Vec3f normal = (p-center).normalize();

        float diff = primRay.dot(normal);
                     

        return std::max(diff,0.f) ;
    }

    
};



int main()
{
    
    Sphere sphere (Vec3f{ 250.0f, 250.0f, 0.0 }, 150.0f );
    Vec3f source{ 100,200,0.0 };
    Vec3f color{ 255,255,255 };
    
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("DIF_SPHERE36.ppm");
    file << "P6\n" << height << " " << width << "\n255\n";

    
    for (float h = 0; h < 500; ++h)
    {
        for (float w = 0; w < 500; ++w)
        {
            Vec3f primRay = { h,w,0.0 };
            
            if (sphere.intersect(primRay))
            {
                
                float facingRatio= sphere.alphaPositive(primRay, source); 
                color = Vec3f{255,0,0}*facingRatio;
                             
                file << unsigned char(color.getX()) << unsigned char(color.getY()) << unsigned char(color.getZ());
                               
            }
            else 
                file << unsigned char(255) << unsigned char(255) << unsigned char(255);
        }
    }

    file.close();

    return 0;

}
```

However. I get smth strange, even when I try to change 'source' coordinates.
Facing ratio is calculated in *alphaPositive function* [This is what a code must generate according to the idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ta4J.png)

Comment: what is "smth strange" ? Please be more specific in describing whats wrong with the code

Comment: Sorry, it basically does not generate a shaded circle(sphere). It also makes just a black circle, not shaded as wanted.

Comment: Pick a point inside the sphere and step through the process for just that one point. Since your circle is black, that means `facingRatio` must be 0 for all points inside the sphere. That means either the equation for `alphaPositive` is wrong or your implementation is wrong. If replacing `std::max` with `std::abs` fixes the problem, you inverted one of the two input vectors to your dot calculation.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code, a very important one is that you need to find a point of intersection of the ray with a sphere and calculate the normal to the sphere at that point. Take a look at https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection

Comment: Dots of intersection are fine. The thing is when I change position of the source of light,  cosine also varies ( as it should)...I saw the code on the site  but I don't want to copy without understanding. There they add extra things making it a bit convoluted to me, while I keep it as simple as possible,  taking into account my little programming experience ( just 7 months) Anyway,  thanks,  I will re-check everything.

Comment: Your sphere and the source of light are located at z=0. Where is your camera located? Your primRays are also with z = 0, which is not good.

Comment: Currently, you treat all as "orthogonal projection" implicitly?
Thinking "orthogonal projection", hit check between "sphere" and "ray" can be treated as 2D as you implemented.
But lighting (rendering) process must be treated as 3D as is.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments.

I made following conclusions:

1. In function `alphaPositive` I had to use `return std::max(diff,0.1f)` instead of `return std::max(diff,0.f)`.
2. Had to change positioning of the *Object* and *Light* by adding z-coordinates.

With that I managed to get a sphere with some effects.

[image: picture]